# Line break issue in PHP mail sending

Tags: php, email, formatting, format, sendmail

Im having problems with line breaks when sending mail with php. The main issue here is, that the line breaks doesnt work in mails with attachment but in plain text it's looks good. We are using IIS server.

```
 $filename = basename($file);
        $file_size = filesize($file);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file))); 
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
        //$from = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $from); // to prevent email injection
        $header = "From: FORM - test \r\n"
              ."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
              ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n"
              ."This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n" 
              ."--".$uid."\r\n"
              ."Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"
              ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
              .$message." 
              ".$companyinfo."\r\n\r\n"
              ."--".$uid."\r\n"
              ."Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"
              ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
              ."Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n"
              .$content."\r\n\r\n"
              ."--".$uid."--";
```

When we see in outlook email client it's showing in paragraph type and other client are missing the line breaks. Any help?

Comment: Set the type of mail e.g. text/html, and put `<br />` tag at the place of `\n`.

Comment: instead of \r\n can use <br /> tag in Headers part?

Comment: tried with <br />, but there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

If your email is of `text/html` content-type then you need to use HTML tag for line breaks:

```
<br />
```

If it is in plain `text/plain` you can simply use

```
\n
```

Comment: if i use <br /> tag in headers part the content is showing completely in paragraph type

Comment: when i select attachment in mail sending the problem is coming, if nt it's working fine